# Can C. elegans be raised on Lactobacillus as the only food source?

Tags: bacteriology, animal-models

I'm interested in running some C. elegans experiments for educational purposes, but would like to avoid having to grow or handle E. coli.  I was wondering if C. elegans need E. coli specifically, or if they would grow well on most (non-pathogenic) kinds of bacteria.

In particular, I'm curious about whether C. elegans would grow on (either live or pasteurized) yoghurt, including strains such as Lactobacillus acidophilus and L. delbrueckii.

I did a quick literature search and found a few articles (like [this](http://aem.asm.org/content/73/20/6404.full)) which talk about screening probiotics in C. elegans by adding them as part of their diet, but I haven't been able to find any reference to using them as the only food source.